# $.ajax() in jQuery 3.1.1 with php bootstrap4

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function`  with this code:

```
$("#fomulariollamada").submit(function(event){
  // cancels the form submission
  event.preventDefault();
  submitForm();
});

function submitForm(){
  // Initiate Variables With Form Content
  var name = $("#NombrePersona").val();
  var tel = $("#NumeroTelefono").val();
  var email = $("#CorreoElectronico").val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "php/process.php",
    data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&tel=" + tel,
    success : function(text){
      if (text == "success"){
        formSuccess();
      }
    }
  });
}

function formSuccess(){
  $( "#msgSubmit" ).removeClass( "hidden-xl-down" );
}
```

I am using `jQuery v3.2.1`. How can I solve that? I'm learning jQuery.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible you are using the slim build of jQuery? The [slim build](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/) does not include the $.ajax function.